# Confusion regarding propositional logic question solution

Tags: logic

The question that I was attempting to answer was the following:

```
Formalise the following statement in propositional logic: 
No birds are carnivorous, unless they fly during the night.
```

Reading this, I first created 2 propositional variables, C = is carnivorous and F = fly's at night. And I thought the answer would be $C \to F$ and $F \to C$ or $F \leftrightarrow C$, as we can also read the statement as: "A bird is carnivorous if and only if it fly's during the night". However the solution to this question only gives: $C \to F$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion is that you think the phrase after "unless" provides necessary and sufficient conditions, when really it only provides necessary conditions. To make this explanation easier, consider the following phrase:

```
No prime number is even, unless it is 2.
```

Clearly, a prime number is even if and only if it is $2$. Here, the phrase after "unless" provides necessary and sufficient conditions for a prime number to be $2$ (namely, that it is $2$). In other words, one can interpret the above statement as

$$ \text{prime number is even} \iff\text{prime number is 2}.$$

However, now, consider the following statement:

```
No prime number is even, unless it is less than 10.
```

Here, the phrase after "unless" provides only
*necessary* conditions for a prime number to be even (namely, that it is less than $10$). This statement is interpreted as

$$ \text{prime number is even} \implies \text{prime number is less than 10}.$$

Thus, in your case, the correct interpretation should be

$$ \text{birds are carnivorous} \implies \text{they fly during the night}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, u explained it really well.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late comment, I was just wondering if there is an easy way to recognise/differentiate when an “unless” satisfies both the necessary and sufficient conditions or when it only satisfies one of them. For the example you gave it was quite easy to see this, but it’s a little less obvious to me for other cases. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think I was clear about this in my answer. The point I was making was: in general, you should assume that it only satisfies "necessary conditions". The statement from your problem is essentially: "Not $P$, unless $Q$". In general, the most you can get from this is: "$P$ is only true whenever $Q$ is also true". As a logical formula, this is written $P \rightarrow Q$.  From the statement "Not $P$, unless $Q$", you can't *a priori* assume $Q \rightarrow P$ or $\neg( Q \rightarrow P)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is only mentioned that "**No birds are carnivorous, unless they fly during the night.**".

> So if a bird is carnivore, it should fly at night.

But this **doesn't necessarily imply** all flying birds are carnivorous birds.

For example, consider the below Venn diagram.

[image]

> So, only $C\rightarrow F$ is true